# Is there a way to take less fall damage?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I find that the fall damage is insanely high (don't know if highest difficulty is even higher).

Is there something I can do to take less fall damage when either running, jumping or falling off of something?

Comment: I have noticed since installing the 1.07 patch that it seems they have increased the height in which you can fall without taking damage. I don't know how much, but enough so that is safe to jump off a small wall without nearly dying... which is a good start

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

As can be read on this [site](http://www.hardcoregamer.com/2015/05/29/you-can-avoid-fall-damage-in-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/151063/) :

> Regarding the fall damage when jumping. Press the jump button twice as you're about to touch the ground to roll & avoid taking damage.

This was tweeted by Marcin Momot, Community Lead & Website Coordinator for CD Projekt Red.

Comment: I think because timing is an issue it might be a good idea to just spam the jump button while you're falling